# Building PhoneGap app for Windows Phone results in Cordova class not found error

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm doing

```
phonegap local build wp8
```

which finishes successfully and creates a `CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap`. When I now try to run this on my Windows Phone device I'm getting a

```
Error initializing Cordova: Class not found
```

alert. Same when building from Visual Studio.

I could need some assistance with that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a Cordova project.

The build of the app was successful:

> cordova build wp8

However, the start of the app resulted in the same alert message.

I solved the problem by removing the windows phone 8 platform

> cordova platforms rm wp8

and adding it again

> cordova platforms add wp8

This might also work for your Phonegap problem.